# Python Flatten Dataframe With Multiple Columns all n-length

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am looking to flatten out a `DataFrame` where there are multiple groups (below: `['a', 'b', 'c']`) of columns, each n columns long (below: n=2). There is also stagnant data which does not need to be flattened (below: ['Misc', 'Year']). Below is an example `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Misc': ['A', 'R', 'B'],
'Year': [1991, 1992, 1993],
'a1': [10, 20, 30],
'a2': [40, 50, 60],
'b1': ['h', 'i', 'j'],
'b2': ['k', 'l', 'm'],
'c1': [4.1, 4.2, 4.3],
'c2': [4.4, 4.5, 4.6] })
```

Produces the following:

```
In [244]: df
Out[244]:
  Misc  Year  a1  a2 b1 b2   c1   c2
0    A  1991  10  40  h  k  4.1  4.4
1    R  1992  20  50  i  l  4.2  4.5
2    B  1993  30  60  j  m  4.3  4.6
```

I want the output to be:

```
In [4]: df1
Out[4]:
  Misc  Year   a  b    c
0    A  1991  10  h  4.1
1    A  1991  40  k  4.4
2    R  1992  20  i  4.2
3    R  1992  50  l  4.5
4    B  1993  30  j  4.3
5    B  1993  60  m  4.6
```

So `[ai, bi, ci]` moves to a single `row` while keeping [Misc, Year]. I am working with thousands of 20,000 row datasets so performance is a big issue. I currently am looping per row to separate them, but was hoping there is a better python function for flattening. I have seen panda's 'melt' function but it seems to only work if there is a single group.

Ultimately I want to create a helper function which would accept an arbitrary number of 'group' columns, 'stagnant' columns, and value for 'n'.

I am currently using pandas but am open to other solutions as well. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's about this:

```
In [11]: df1 = df[["Misc", "Year"] + [c for c in df.columns if c[-1] == "1"]]

In [12]: df1 = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1] == "1" else x)

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
  Misc  Year   a  b    c
0    A  1991  10  h  4.1
1    R  1992  20  i  4.2
2    B  1993  30  j  4.3

In [14]: df2 = df[["Misc", "Year"] + [c for c in df.columns if c[-1] == "2"]]

In [15]: df2 = df2.rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1] == "2" else x)

In [16]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[16]:
  Misc  Year   a  b    c
0    A  1991  10  h  4.1
1    R  1992  20  i  4.2
2    B  1993  30  j  4.3
0    A  1991  40  k  4.4
1    R  1992  50  l  4.5
2    B  1993  60  m  4.6
```

You could do this as a comprehension, or function, more generally:

```
In [21]: pd.concat([df[["Misc", "Year"] + [c for c in df.columns if c[-1] == str(i)]]
                     .rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1] == str(i) else x)
                    for i in range(1, 3)])
Out[21]:
  Misc  Year   a  b    c
0    A  1991  10  h  4.1
1    R  1992  20  i  4.2
2    B  1993  30  j  4.3
0    A  1991  40  k  4.4
1    R  1992  50  l  4.5
2    B  1993  60  m  4.6
```

---

If you want to eke out some more performance, you're going to want to do this concat in numpy and then repeat the index (though I'm not convinced it's worth the small gain that will give you).

Comment: Thanks Andy! What if I want to preserve the 'ith' column index? Is it possible to create a brand new column, say 'N_index', within the concat function and assign it the value of str(i)?

Comment: @kolze100 IIUC I would (lazily) do this with `.sort_index()`, then `.reset_index()`. In some sense the index you wanted wasn't really coming from anywhere and I don't think it can be done during concat.

Comment: Well I actually intend to perform some logic on it. I want to use the 'Year' column and the 'ith' number to get a Year-Month combination. For example: i=2 Year=1992 would get put into a 'Date' column as 'Feb-1992'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out. I created each dataframe in a for loop, appending each to a list, then concatenating them all after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical application for reshape/melt type functions, so you're probably going to have to roll your own. Here's a solution that should be relatively performant provided `(# groups)*n` is not too big:

Make two dataframes, one with columns `[Misc, Year, a1, b1, c1]`, the other with `[Misc, Year, a2, b2, c2]` and concatenate them vertically.

This can be automated for arbitrary numbers of groups and n values, provided that the column names have a uniform convention like `<letter><number>` as in your example. You'll have to do a bit of regex parsing on the column names to determine which columns go together in each data frame.

Make a list called `subframes` of all these dataframes and concatenate them together with `pd.concat(subframes)`.